# HTML Selected Value Reordering via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given the following HTML selects:

```
<select id="HtmlSelect1">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="HtmlSelect2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="HtmlSelect3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="HtmlSelect4">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
</select>
```

Scenario 1: If I change the selected value in HtmlSelect4 to 2, the selected value for HtmlSelect2 should change to 3 and the selected value for HtmlSelect3 should change to 4.

Scenario 2: If I change the selected value for HtmlSelect2 to 3, the selected value for HtmlSelect3 should change to 2.

In summary, I am reordering the selected value of the other drop down lists based upon one of the other drop down lists being changed. How do I accomplish this in JavaScript?

Note: The number of drop down lists and options could vary as these are being driven by data in a database.

Below is what I tried that should have theoretically worked for scenario 1, but didn't. It's a start in the direction of what I am trying to do.

```
<script>
        function SelectChange(selectControl)
        {
            var controlDiv = document.getElementById("SomeDiv");
            var controlSelects = controlDiv.getElementsByTagName("select");
            for (var selectIndex = 0; selectIndex < controlSelects.length; selectIndex++)
            {
                if (controlSelects[selectIndex].id.indexOf("SelectControlPrefix") != -1)
                {
                    if (controlSelects[selectIndex].value >= selectControl.value)
                    {
                        for (var optionIndex = 0; optionIndex < controlSelects[selectIndex].options.length; optionIndex++)
                        {
                            if (controlSelects[selectIndex].options[optionIndex].value == controlSelects[selectIndex].options.value + 1)
                            {
                                controlSelects[selectIndex].options[optionIndex].selected = "selected";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? What were your results?

Comment: Yes, I tried some script I created which should have theoretically at least worked in scenario 1, but didn't. Basically, I got all of the drop down lists via JS and then checked if the value was >= the value of the changed drop down list and then if so update the selected value to be the current + 1. It didn't error out and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant parts of your script, and elaborate on how it didn't work? Code is better than words here, it would greatly help us to understand your question.

Comment: do you have only two scenarios? I couldn't understand your reordering algorithm.

Comment: There should only be two scenarios. This is to reorder records from a database as they should appear in a UI. I could easily use up and down arrow buttons to accomplish this, but in this case I've been requested to use drop down lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having some trouble understanding the expected behavior, so I'll abstract it away in a function (**Update 2** working as intended; added some comments to better explain my solution):

```
/* Returns a list of pairs [#element, value] to be updated */
function myBehaviour(n,o,v) {
    var ret = [["#HtmlSelect" + n, v]]; // The new value should be what the user selected
    // Shifts the other values, to the left of right
    while ( n > o ) {
        var next = $("#HtmlSelect" + (o+1));
        ret.push(["#HtmlSelect" + o, next.val()]);
        o++;
    }
    while ( n < o ) {
        var next = $("#HtmlSelect" + (o-1));
        ret.push(["#HtmlSelect" + o, next.val()]);
        o--;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

That said, here's how you could accomplish this using jQuery:

```
var old;
$("select").focus(function() {
    old = $(this).val(); // Saves the old value, before the change
}).change(function(e) {
    var newValue = $(this).val(); // Save the new value
    $(this).val(old); // Reverts to old, will change later

    var oldPosition = parseInt(findOld(newValue)); // Find where the old value was
    var newPosition = parseInt(this.id.substring("HtmlSelect".length));
    $.each(myBehaviour(newPosition,oldPosition,newValue), function(i,pair) {
        $(pair[0]).val(pair[1]); // Updates all them only after the correct positions were found
    });
    old = $(this).val(); // Saves the old again, in case the select is changed again
});

function findOld(value) {
    return $("select").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == value;
    }).attr("id").substring("HtmlSelect".length);
}
```

If you need pure JavaScript, the code will get a little longer, but it can be accomplished by using `document.getElementById`, `onchange`, `childNodes`, `nodeValue` etc.

Comment: This is to reorder records from a database as they should appear in a UI. I could easily use up and down arrow buttons to accomplish this, but in this case I've been requested to use drop down lists. jQuery is an option.

Comment: +1, but consider using `$.each()` instead of `Array.forEach()`, as it's still more portable.

Comment: Answer updated. Still not perfect, but should work for your two examples, tested on jsFiddle (sorry, no account, couldn't save and share). See note above.